# React Native: Invariant Violation: Element type invalid:expected string or a class/function but got: undefined

Tags: react-native

I am trying to display wordpress posts in a react-native app.

The following are the contents on the Blog.js file.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, TouchableOpacity, Text, Alert, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { HTML } from 'react-native-render-html';

class BlogItem extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  blogChoice = () => {
    this.props.choosePost(this.props.id);
  }

  render() {
    let blogItems = `
      <a href=${this.props.id} style="textDecorationLine: none; color: #000000;  textAlign: center">
        <img src=${this.props.imageSrc} />
        <h1>${this.props.title}</h1>
        ${this.props.excerpt}
      </a>
    `;
    return (
      <View style={{borderBottomWidth: 2, borderBottomColor: '#000000', borderStyle: 'solid'}}>
        <HTML html={blogItems} onLinkPress={()=>this.blogChoice()} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export class Blog extends React.Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {blogLoaded: false};
  }

  chooseBlog = (blogID) => {
    console.log(`Blog ID chosen: ${blogID}`);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // return fetch('https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/reactnative.travel.blog/posts')
    return fetch('https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/myglobomantics.wordpress.com/posts')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
          blogLoaded: true,
          blogList: Array.from(responseJson.posts)
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>

        { this.state.blogLoaded && (
          <View style={{ paddingTop: 40 }}>
            <FlatList
              data={this.state.blogList}
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.ID.toString()}
              renderItem={({item}) => 
                <BlogItem
                  id={item.ID}
                  title={item.title}
                  imageSrc={item.featured_image}
                  excerpt={item.excerpt}
                  choosePost={this.chooseBlog}
                />
              }
            />
          </View>
        )}

        { !this.state.blogLoaded && (
            <View style={{ paddingTop: 30 }}>
              <Text> LOADING </Text>
            </View>
        )}

      </View>    
    );
  }

}
```

And app.js file uses the component as:

```
import { Blog } from './app/views/Blog.js';
```

where it creates a stackNavigation.

```
const MyRoutes = createStackNavigator({
    HomeRT: {
      screen: Home
    },
    BlogRT: {
      screen: Blog
    },
  },
  {
    'initialRouteName': 'HomeRT'
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(MyRoutes);
```

However when I navigate to the Blog Component, I keep getting this error:

```
Device: (96:380) Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.

This error is located at:
    in RCTView
    in BlogItem
    in RCTView
    in u
    in RCTView
    in RCTScrollView
    in ScrollView
    in z
    in b
    in RCTView
    in RCTView
    in Blog
    in t
    in RCTView
    in RCTView
    in RCTView
    in f
    in RCTView
    in f
    in C
    in t
    in n
    in RCTView
    in n
    in RCTView
    in f
    in S
    in t
    in n
    in RCTView
    in t
    in t
    in p
    in r
    in n
    in RCTView
    in RCTView
    in n
    in n
    in v
    in RCTView
    in RCTView
    in c

This error is located at:
    in n
    in RCTView
    in RCTView
    in n
    in n
    in v
    in RCTView
    in RCTView
    in c
```

I have check all the values I am getting from the wordpress API and they are non-null values. Also I tried to remove the BlogItem component and build it incrementally, but could not pin point what causes the error. What am I going wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the curlies from the HTML import:

```
import { HTML } from 'react-native-render-html';
```

I don't think you need destructuring here. I think you want the default export.

What's happening is `HTML` is `undefined` and therefore not a "valid element".

---

If your module has named exports:

```
// cool-stuff.js
module.exports = {
  SomeCoolThing: () => console.log('some cool thing'),
  SomeOtherCoolThing: () => console.log('some other cool thing')
}
```

Then you can either import the whole thing and reference the items statically:

```
import CoolStuff from './cool-stuff.js';

CoolStuff.SomeCoolThing();
```

or you can destructure it on import to get just the piece(s) you need:

```
import {SomeCoolThing} from './cool-stuff.js'

SomeCoolThing();
```

But if a module just has a default export:

```
// cool-stuff.js
module.exports = () => console.log('some other cool thing')
```

Then destructuring makes no sense:

```
import {SomeCoolThing} from './cool-stuff.js'

SomeCoolThing(); // doesn't exist. blows up.
```

You just want the default export, and you can call it whatever you want:

```
import SoCool from './cool-stuff.js'

SoCool(); // works
```

Comment: Wow it works, but can you please explain in the answer how and why?

Comment: Updated the answer to try to explain. Not sure how clear it is. I'm tired. Happy to try to clarify if it doesn't make sense.